# how to i make the content respect the navbar and chat in my application. using express js and tailwind css

Tags: html, express, tailwind-css

I have a layout that i use for all the routes in my site. it has navigation bar and chat in the left. i want the new routes to include it and also have a margin that starts where the navbar and chat ends.

```
<!-- public/layout.ejs -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Simple Chat App</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.17/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100">
    <div class="navbar bg-gray-800 text-white h-16 flex items-center justify-between px-4 w-full fixed top-0 left-0" style="z-index: 100;">

      <%- include('navbar') %>
    </div>
    <div class="chat bg-gray-100 border-r border-gray-300 h-full fixed top-16 left-0 w-80" style="z-index: 50;">

      <%- include('chat') %>
    </div>
    
  
  <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<%- include('layout') %>
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

**This is the new route that includes the layout but the hello world is hidden at the top left of the window**

i was trying with marings and stuff but aswell as not really working well its not responsive to the site.
im new to css and need help with that.
also i use tailwind css as mentioned above